# Resource for learning Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am looking for an online resource to learn the Spring MVC stack.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I have used this tutorial to start. I found it very helpful.

http://static.springframework.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/

Comment: This is a great resource that will do nicely. Thank you very much!

Comment: If you want an interactive course try this: http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/springmvc-intro

Answer (score 2):

Pick up a copy of [Spring in Action](http://www.manning.com/walls3/) from Manning Publications.

Fantastic book with lots of great examples, theory and practical deployment tips.

Answer (score 2):

If you want an interactive web based training course, try this: http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/springmvc-intro

Answer (score 1):

The best lesson I can recommend is having a good look at the [spring mvc build of appfuse](http://appfuse.org). Make sure you get the full source of the app, so that you can see all details of the controllers.

Also offline the [apress book on spring MVC](http://apress.com/book/view/9781590595848) isn't too bad.

Answer (score 0):

You read some of my tutorials, it will help you get Started with Spring MVC [here](http://shreymalhotra.me/blog/tutorial/springmvc/spring-mvc-hello-springworld/)

Answer (score 0):

[GONTUSERIES - The best youtube Spring MVC playlist I can recommend to all](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iCQspqBpOB0&list=PLBgMUB7xGcO31B2gBmy1igpZn6LK78-CJ)