# spring framework tutorial using mysql database for a simple hello world application without using maven and hibernate in eclipse

Tags: java, mysql, spring-mvc

I am new to spring and java. I am trying to learn spring framework for 1 months but i failed. Is there any small tutorials that uses mysql database with spring framework but without using hibernate and maven in eclipse that will help me to learn spring in some amount.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resource for learning Spring MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/494537/resource-for-learning-spring-mvc)

Comment: yeah its possibly the duplicate of the Resource for learning Spring MVC but i want only the specific part of it only the mysql and spring in eclipse ide.

Comment: In my opinion it would be harder without Maven, because of the many dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

There are many books (e.g. Spring In Action) and tutorial out there that you can check.

One online tutorial that I would recommend is:
[JPA – Hibernate Example using Spring Framework MVC 3.1.](http://www.flacom.com/jpa-hibernate-example-using-spring-framework-mvc-3-1/)

The tutorial is not yet so comprehensive, but there you would be guided in every single step how to make a working web application. The tutorial requires no Maven knowledge, but Hibernate indeed.

Good luck in learning Spring Framework.